# (Reading CSV file) scanf skip to next line of input after pattern mismatch

Tags: c, csv

I want to give an error message if scanf encounters a mismatch and then continue reading the rest of the inputs. My current code goes into an infinite loop if one of the inputs isn't formatted correctly.

Expected input:

```
101,Betty,Hay,123 Main St.,23
234,Sheila,Benn,937 Ash Ave.,46
384,Ron,Jewell,3991 Cedar Ave.,30
291,Bill,Read,83 Crescent St.,19
103,Alexander,Ott,100 2nd St.,21
115,Tricia,Munson,585 Oxen Ave.,28
118,Sam,Munson,585 Oxen Ave.,35
110,Valerie,Parker,1513 Copper Rd.,37
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        int id;
        char first[80], last[80], addr[80];
        int age;
        scanf("%d,%80[^,],%80[^,],%80[^,],%d", &id, first, last, addr, &age);
        if (feof(stdin)) break;
        printf("id=%d first=%s last=%s addr=%s age=%d\n",
               id, first, last, addr, age);
        sum += age;
        count++;
    }

    printf("Average age is %f\n", (float)sum / count);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to fix this by putting scanf inside an if statement comparing it to the expected number of reads, this worked for displaying the error message but doesn't help reading the rest of the input. Is there a way to skip to the next line of input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test the result from `scanf()` directly.  In this context (and most others), I'd recommend using `fgets()` and `sscanf()` over plain `scanf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int lineno = 0;
    char line[4096];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
    {
        int id;
        char first[80], last[80], addr[80];
        int age;
        lineno++;
        if (sscanf(line, "%d,%79[^,],%79[^,],%79[^,],%d", &id, first, last, addr, &age) != 5)
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid data in line %d:\n%s", lineno, line);
        else
        {
            printf("id=%d first=%s last=%s addr=%s age=%d\n",
                   id, first, last, addr, age);
            sum += age;
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("Average age is %f\n", (float)sum / count);

    return 0;
}
```

Amongst the fixes are:

1. Checking the input function (`fgets()`) directly — using `feof()` is usually not appropriate.
2. Checking that the `sscanf()` call found 5 values.
3. Making sure that the strings do not overflow the buffers allocated; `sscanf()` et al need a size excluding the null byte at the end — hence the change from 80 to 79 in the format.
4. Being able to report the whole line that was flawed because it was all read in.  With `scanf()` instead, it has chomped an indeterminate initial part of the line, leaving who knows what left with which to report the error.  Here, you got the whole line and can report an error more meaningfully.  I included a line number to improve things still more.

Answer (score 1):

When `scanf()` fails to read it stops at the place of failure. You need to ignore the rest of the line.

One way is to read character by character until you see newline character. You may use `getc()` function for that. You may also use fgets() to read the rest in one go. Then resume using `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `scanf` is not the best idea for this exact reason. I would suggest using `fgets` to capture the entire line of text from `stdin` into your character array. Then use `strtok` to tokenize the string and process each input.

Perhaps something like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        int id;
        char line[240], * token;
        char first[80], last[80], addr[80];
        int age;

        if (fgets(line,240,stdin) == NULL) break;
        line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0'; /* remove \n */
        id = atoi(strtok(line,","));
        strcpy(first,strtok(NULL,","));
        strcpy(last,strtok(NULL,","));
        strcpy(addr,strtok(NULL,","));
        age = atoi(strtok(NULL,","));
        printf("id=%d first=%s last=%s addr=%s age=%d\n",
               id,first, last, addr, age);
        sum += age;
        count++;
    }

    printf("Average age is %f\n", (float)sum / count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I agree with the use of `fgets()`.  I personally would not recommend `strtok()` for this (or most other) jobs.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It can lead to some unwanted cases. I do like your approach better.

Comment: @dmitri Since the last element is a number, atoi basically takes care of that for us. You're right though, it's cleaner to manually remove it.

Comment: @dmitri: there's no particular need to remove the newline since the field before it is a number and the conversion code will ignore the newline.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Looks like beat you to it! :)

Comment: Yeah — I was busy and got there 20 seconds or so after you did.  But I agree with your point, funnily enough!

Comment: OK, sounds good :) I didn't pay attention to the last expected.